# Was not playing or did not play?

Tags: progressive-aspect

I did not play well today and I lost.

I was not playing well today and I lost.

Without context do they mean thé same ?

I think was not playing implies that the bad play did not last the whole match.

I think the first sentence is better .

Comment: I think the opposite. You did not play well in that particular match, or you were playing badly all day and consequently lost the match.

Comment: No, they do not mean the same nor would their translation into French mean the same thing. The continuous stresses the activity. The simple past, the fait accompli.

Comment: but  with my example what is the best progressive or simple because I  am speaking of  a particular match simple must be better. In french both will be translated by  passé compose . J'ai mal joué le match (only the match) ou j'ai mal joue aujourd'hui et j'ai perdu (implying all day long including the match )

Comment: It's very unlikely a speaker would choose the second (continuous) verb form in order to convey the fact that he played badly ***all day*** (including other matches he played on the same day). So *literally* the two are equivalent. But as @Lambie says, the continuous puts more emphasis on the activity ***as it took place*** in the past; simple past puts more emphasis on the ***end result, outcome***. It's Just an almost imperceptible shift of nuance, nothing important.

Comment: Je ne jouait pas bien aujourd'hui versus Je n'ai pas bien joué aujourd'hui. And conversationally, one could very well say: Boy, I was playing badly today. I don't think that past continuous is passé composé.

Comment: Yes, if you are speaking of a particular match the past simple is fine. The continuous tense would also be possible, and it _could_ give the additional meaning that you were playing badly all day.

Comment: In French we would use " je n ai pas bien joué aujourd'hui "not "je ne jouais pas bien aujourd'hui " it is not always passé composé but in this case it is

Comment: Why a native would not use progressive if he did not play well the whole day it is continuous activity – 
Yves

Comment: Random, essentially irrelevant comment: The OP contains the first occurrence I have ever noticed of a spell checker’s messing with a normally francophone author’s spelling in English. “Do they mean the same” has been very **un**helpfully “corrected” to “do they mean **thé** same”? Is this The Software Demon’s way of making up for all the times I’ve typed, say, *prix* and had it changed to *prim*?